# Массив указателей на char

Tags: c++

Не понимаю, как работает. Пишу так:

```
int a = 100, b = 200, c = 300, d = 400;
int *w[][2] = { {&a, &b}, {&c, &d}}; // массив указателей на int-переменные

cout << *w[0][1] << endl; // 200
```

А пишу так:

```
// строковая константа генерит  указатель на себя 
char *p[][2] =  {{"yellow", "green"}, {"orange", "blue"}};

cout << *p[0][0] << endl; // выдает первый символ индекса [0][0]
```

Что за? А если p[0][0], то да, строка нормальная, это ж ведь указатель почему так? А если p[0] то адрес...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все правильно: p[0][0] - это Си-строка (http://www.rsdn.ru/article/cpp/cstr.xml), ограниченная нулем, с которыми ostream замечательно работает. Вы работает с двумерным массивом `p`, где первый элемент - адрес линейного одномерного массива `p[0]`, в котором хранятся указатели на строки.

Comment: так разве массив указателей *w и *p не идентичны? Ведь в обоих [0][0] лежат лишь адреса, и значение можно получить лишь оператором "*"? Почему во втором случае выдает символ, а не строку, ведь по сути он должен указывать нас строку.

Comment: по-порядку: во втором случае указатель указывает на первый символ в строке. Си-строка ограничена нулевым символом, так что запись cout << p[0][0] приводит к тому, что из памяти считывается последовательно по одному символу char до тех пор, пока не встретиться '\0'. В качестве итератора по символам выступает указатель сперва на первый элемент строки (p[0][0]), затем он инкрементируется, и так до конца. Таково общее правило работы с си-строками.

Comment: @vladimir_ki, не обманывайте людей.

>Вы работает с двумерным массивом p, где первый элемент - адрес     линейного одномерного массива p[0], в котором хранятся     указатели на строки

На самом деле начиная с адреса p (он же &p[0][0]) лежат друг за другом 4 указателя на строки, т.е. p[][2] это **реальный двумерный массив**, а не та структура данных, что его изображает в большинстве пособий и лекций.

Comment: @avp, я не вижу в своем ответе противоречия вашим рассуждениями. В чем я именно не прав? Что имеется ввиду под словами "реальный двумерный массив"?

Comment: Вы пишете, что в первом элементе массива p **находится адрес массива p[0], В КОТОРОМ указатели на строки**. 

На самом деле в первом элементе (p[0][0]) находится указатель непосредственно на текст первой строки ("yellow"), во втором (p[0][1]) на "green" и т.д. 

Эти указатели лежат в памяти плотно друг за другом, и **никаких** указателей, ссылающихся на них компилятор для такого кода не генерит.

Comment: Во! Вы говорите что в p[0][0] содержится указатель на "yellow", т.е адрес на строку, верно? Какого чёрта оно тогда выдает мне строку, а не адрес?

Comment: А потому, что указатель на текст и есть указатель на первый символ текста. Если вы хотите узнать значение адреса, необходимо использовать конструкцию получения адреса - &p[0][0] (адрес адреса), только зачем он вам?

Comment: А это оператор << в c++ для данного случая так сконструирован. 

Если хотите реально разбираться берите 

1) отладчик 

2) ассемблерный код (например g++ -S t.cpp сделает файл t.s)

Comment: @avp, Сам массив `p` точно будет единым блоком без всяких пропусков и пр. - это бесспорно. Но кем гарантировано, что все компиляторы будут размещать код строк, на которые указывают элементы массива, именно так, как вы говорите? Кстати, что же все-такие такое "реальный двумерный массив"?

Comment: Гарантий, что **все** компиляторы будут делать так, дать не могу. Можете написать свой, который будет делать, как Вы описали. 

Реальный двумерный массив, это непрерывная область памяти в которой размещаются подряд все элементы (многомерного) массива.

В C можно моделировать (обычно это делают для динамических массивов) многомерный массив с заранее (при компиляции) не известной величиной всех размерностей. Для двумерного массива обычно берут (как Вы, @vladimir_ki описали) вектор указателей на строки, а сами строки это вектора нужного типа. К элементам можно обращаться по [i][j]. 

(нет места.

Comment: Ну "реальный" вероятно неудачный термин. Просто массив `arr[n][m]` представляет  в памяти одномерный массив `arr'[n*m]` и индексируется так, что `arr[i][j] == arr'[i*m+j]` В разных языках многомерные массивы располагаются по-разному: по строкам, как здесь (первым меняется последний индекс) или по столбцам, как, например в фортране.

Comment: Вот так бы сказали. Логика конечно потрясает, когда указатель указывает на int-значение - выдает адрес, а когда на первый элемент символьного массива например - то выдает все элементы символьного массива.
char *u[] = "PROGRAMMING";
char *pi;
pi = &u[0];
cout << pi;
Выдает **не адресс**, а все символы. Всем спасибо за обсуждение :)

Comment: @Супер герой, у меня лимит комментариев кончился, поэтому пишу в ответе на Ваш комментарий 

    Вот так бы сказали. Логика конечно потрясает...

А плюсы не очень логичный язык.


Answer (score 2):

В строке `cout << *p[0][0] << endl;` звёздочка лишняя. p имеет тип `char***`, p[0] имеет тип `char**`, а p[0][0] имеет тип `char*` - указатель на первый символ строки. А ты его зачем-то разыменовываешь.